# jQuery SVG plugin: how to display a predefined SVG image

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to display an .svg file in a HTML page using jQuery SVG (http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). It should be pretty simple but I can not get it to work.

The only output I get is a big box (which is my div styled by CSS) and the words, "Error loading:" in the box. I've tried it in Chrome and Firefox. In Chrome I had to run it as "chromium-browser --disable-web-security".

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #484; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svgdom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svganim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready ( function () {
            $('#canvas').svg({loadURL: 'lion.svg'});
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='console'></div>
    <div id='canvas'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that the url is loaded using a `jquery.ajax` call. So I don't think it will work if the lion.svg is local. For me it works if I do:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #484; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.svg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.svgdom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.svganim.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready ( function () {
            $('#canvas').svg({loadURL: 'http://keith-wood.name/lion.svg'});
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='console'></div>
    <div id='canvas'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahh - it seems obvious now. Thanks. I also found a nifty way to get around it for local development. If you have python installed, go to the directory where the files are and run "python -m SimpleHTTPServer".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use script to include the standalone svg file, but you can if you want to (as shown by your example). Personally I find it cleaner/easier to just include the svg by reference (e.g `<object data="my.svg">`), but it's up to you to choose whichever way you want.

Here are [some more ways to include svg](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML) (from the [SVG Primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html)), which don't require the use of scripting.